# Python dict to user format string

Tags: python, string, join, dictionary

What is the easiest way to convert Python dict e.g.:

```
a = {'a': 'value', 'b': 'another_value', ...}
```

into string using user format e.g.:

```
'%s - %s\n'
```

so it gives me:

```
a - value
b - another_value
```

This works, but maybe there is something shorter/better using map (without iterating over collection)

```
''.join(['%s %s\n' % o for o in a.items()])
```

Comment: There's no need for that list, just do: `'\n'.join('%s %s' % o for o in a.items())`

Comment: `map` still iterates over the collection, it just happens that sometimes it is faster and sometimes slower than an explicit loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can omit the square brackets to avoid building the intermediate list:

```
''.join('%s %s\n' % o for o in a.items())
```

Since you're asking about `map`, here is one way to write it using `map`:

```
''.join(map(lambda o:'%s %s\n' % o, a.items()))
```

It's a matter of preference, but I personally find it harder to read than the original version.

Comment: `map` when using `lambda` is almost certainly slower than just using `for`. Of course you can avoid the lambda here but then it is definitely harder to read: `''.join(map('%s %s\n'.__mod__, a.items()))`

Comment: I just thought there is shorter version without iterating over list, but I see this first version is simply what I need :) Thank You.

Answer (score 5):

I'd write this as:

```
>>> print '\n'.join(' '.join(o) for o in a.items())
a value
b another_value
```

Or:

```
>>> print '\n'.join(map(' '.join, a.items()))
a value
b another_value
```

Comment: I may be reading the question wrong, but to me "using user format" suggests that the format string is essentially a parameter.

Comment: YES. Joining string is a parameter, so I could create function `def dict_to_str(dict_obj, join_str_format)`